# Bash - running programs in background still causes script to wait

Tags: bash

I wrote a simple wrapper script for my favorite editor, nedit. It will take a list of arguments and open all non-gzipped files in one window and it will take each gzipped file, zcat them to a temporary file, and open those in separate windows. However, running the `nedit` causes the script to wait until the window is closed, even if I use `&` or `nohup`. Am I missing something here?

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a nongzipped
for file in $@; do
    if file $file | grep -q gzip; then
        timestamp=$(date +"%F_%T")
        tempfile="tmp_$timestamp"
        $( zcat $file > $tempfile )
        $( nedit -background lightskyblue3 $tempfile & )
        $( rm $tempfile )
    else
        nongzipped+=("$file")
    fi
done

if [ ${#nongzipped[@]} -ne 0 ]; then
    $( nedit ${nongzipped[@]} & )
fi
```

Comment: You're overusing command substitution; they are only necessary for capturing the output of a command, not for simply running the command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shell induced by the command substitution `$(...)` cannot exit until its background jobs complete. (Compare `sleep &` with `$( sleep & )`.) You don't need them anyway, so just remove them.

```
if file $file | grep -q gzip; then
    timestamp=$(date +"%F_%T")
    tempfile="tmp_$timestamp"
    zcat $file > $tempfile
    nedit -background lightskyblue3 $tempfile &
    rm $tempfile
else
    nongzipped+=("$file")
fi
```

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding when to use backticks or command substitution. I was under the impression that in a shell script you need to use backticks or command substitution to run external programs, like `ls`, `rm`, or `zcat`.

Comment: No, you only need them if you want to capture the output as a string. For example, `result=$(some_command arg1 arg2)` will store the output of `some_command` in the variable `result`, and `some_command "$(other_command)"` captures the output of `other_command` to use as the argument to `some_command`. (`some_command other_command`, on the other hand, would pass the literal string "other_command" as the argument.)

Answer (score 1):

Do you *really* need `$(command)` here? This syntax is usually used to get the output of `command` and assign it to a variable. That's probably the reason your script has to wait.

You'd better call your program without any special syntax, just `program arg1 arg2 &`